# Pull text from webpage using selenium not working

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to pull some text from a webpage.  The page source that I want to pull data from is:

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="drx_dotted">
        <td class="drx_first">
            <span name="pharmacy"
                  longitude="-82.531457"
                  latitude="42.617612"
                  pharmacyname="CVS Pharmacy #"
                  address="1025 St Clair River Dr"
                  city="Algonac"
                  state="MI"
                  zip="48001"
                  phone="8107944941">
            </span>
            <p>
                <strong>CVS Pharmacy #</strong><br />
                1025 St Clair River Dr<br />
                Algonac, MI 48001<br />
                1-810-794-4941
            </p>
            <p>
                <a class=""
                   data-ajax="true"
                   data-ajax-method="post"
                   data-ajax-success="UpdateSearchPharmacyList"
                   href="/pfdn/SharedPharmacy/AddNetworkPharmacy?pharmacyNABP=2352324&amp;language=English">Add Pharmacy
                    <span class='HiddenText'> CVS Pharmacy #</span>
                </a>
            </p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>
                Retail
            </p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>
                Not applicable
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

I want to pull the "Not applicable" near the bottom of the HTML code.  It is the "p" in the third "td" in the HTML source code. There are also a bunch of these, so I want to pull all these tags at once into a python list.

Here is the selenium code I'm using to find the HTML:

```
x = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
    '//[@id="divSearchResultContainer"]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/p')
```

When I type print(x) it prints out this:

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x101f98210>,
 <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x101f98250>,
 <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x101f98290>]
```

So selenium has found and pull three instances (which is correct, it was supposed to find three).  However, when I try to pull the text using;

```
print x[0].text
```

the output is:

```
None
```

I've tried a bunch of variations, even trying to find each element individually, but it's still not working.  Has anyone had this problem? How can I resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: What are you expecting the text output of `print x[0].text` to be?

Comment: I don't know much about selenium, but print `dir(x)` and see what is valid for it

Comment: Wow, sorry I made a mistake.  The output for print x[0].text is "None", but it should be "Not applicable"  Thanks for pointing that out, Richard.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have multiple `tr` tags, get the appropriate one. Use [`find_element_by_xpath()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_xpath) to find a single element instead of a list and use the following xpath:

```
'//[@id="divSearchResultContainer"]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/p
```

The python code:

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
'//[@id="divSearchResultContainer"]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/p')
```

Note the `[1]` after the `tr`. This is how we are saying to look at the first `tr` tag only.

---

Also note that the `xpath` you have looks fragile - this is because of the use of indexing: give me second `div` in this div, and then second `div` in that etc. Posting the complete contents of the element with `divSearchResultContainer` id would help to provide your with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for xpath, I haven't tested but xpath has last() operator which is what you want.

```
"//tbody//tr//td[last()]/p[last()]/text()"
```